# How to storage in runtime the data of GameObject? - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to save the attribute of a gameObject but in runtime without Serializing anything. This I want to do when the object is selected. That way when I touch the paint button for example, paint the object that was selected.

What I tested so far is the use of the event `OnMouseDown` that is in the GameObject script and I also made another empty GameObject with the script that saves the attribute, but I can't save for example the name of the selected object. Although it shows it in the Debug.Log but returns log at the time of assigning it.

I applied the same logic in a new project with `ObjSelect`, `SelectScript`, `ButtonsEventsScript` scripts with the same prefabs and GameObjects but without Vuforia and it worked great.

Repository: https://github.com/emicalvacho/MapaMentalAR

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjSelect : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string nombre;

    void OnEnable() {
        SelectScript.OnName += HandlerOnName;
    }   

    void OnDisable() {
        SelectScript.OnName -= HandlerOnName;
    }

    void HandlerOnName(string str){
        Debug.Log("NOMBRE DEL OBJETO SETEADO: " + str);
        nombre = str;
    }

    public string getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }
}
```

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class SelectScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cube;
    private GameObject findObj;
    public GameObject gameObjectManager;

    public delegate void _OnName (string str);
    public static event _OnName OnName;

    private bool band;

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if(OnName != null)
            OnName(cube.name);
    }
}
```

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ButtonsEventsScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ObjSelect script;
    private GameObject obj;

    public void ChangeColor(){
        Debug.Log("OBJETO A PINTAR ES: " + script.getNombre());
    }
}
```

[image: Return null the string]

[image: Prefab cube]

I don't have any error messages, but it returns a null instead of the name of the selected GameObject.

If anyone has any other way of doing this, I ask you to help me for more than a week that I've been stuck. I already asked in other forums and nobody gives me a solution or a way to solve.

Comment: Would you please share your ObjetosSeleccionados script?

Comment: @ErikOverflow ready

Comment: You send the value stored in `public GameObject obj;`, did you ever set this field to contain anything?

Comment: @Draco18s yes. There is configured the prefab in the Inspector

Comment: I just tried passing the message between events and it doesn't return anything.

Comment: You have two sections of code both called `SelectScript`. One of them has `Debug.Log` the other has a field called `cube` that shows up in your picture of the inspector. This should not compile.

Comment: It works correctly for me

Comment: @Draco18s No, are two differents version

Comment: @Innat3 Mmm, Is it because I'm working with Vuforia? I don't know

Comment: @Calvin no, it is not dependent on anything else, try it out on a new project just with the scripts `ObjSelect `, `SelectScript ` and `ButtonsEventsScript` (The last 3 you attached).

Comment: @Innat3 ok, I was just gonna do that. Then I communicate the results

Comment: @Innat3 Effectively the idea in another project works, so I don't know why this happens in the other project.

Comment: @Calvin you probably have two scripts with the same name or some stuff like that, just look carefully

Comment: @Innat3 I have all the different scripts and the problem continues. There I edited my question and there's my repository. If you have time to try it and tell me if the same thing happens to you, I would appreciate it.